# Can anyone explain the following code for sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a piece of code here which I am finding difficult in understanding the sorting mechanism.
I am new to programming, can anyone help me in understanding

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

var numArray = [140000, 104, 99];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
console.log(numArray);
```

Comment: internal use of sort of javascript, will be founded by any sort math algorith, in base iterate all items in array an use an function to know if order is DESC or ASC or any, in base the return function as you put

Comment: Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Comment: Have you read the doc? [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: yes but when you do this => numArray.sort(sortNumber); 
what are the values passed in sortNumber(a, b) .. what are a and b values taken

Comment: If you're looking for an explanation on how/why this works: The parameter for the sort function needs to be a function that takes parameters a and b. It answers the question "is a "bigger" than b?" The function returns one of three things: 1) a negative value, which indicates that **a** is smaller than **b**, 2) 0, which indicates the values are equal 3) a positive value, which indicates that a is bigger than b. The sort function iterates through the list, calls this function for each pair of elements and based on the results, returns a list sorted with the function you defined.

Comment: So the pairs will be like (140000, 104) and (104,99) and (99,140000) ??
and computes like you said in your explanation.